# How to change grid panel`s visibility while i click on a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 5 Grid panels and 5 Buttons. When i click button number 1 then Grid number 1 will be visible and others will be hide just like as a TabContrl. Now how can i do it ?

I want to do it using XAML or using converters.

Edit1:

Thank`s every one. Now i can understand about my mistake. Now please tell me how can i do that using Code.

thank`s.

Comment: How about using a TabControl and styling it as needed?

Comment: I'd use event handlers in the code behind if i were doing it

Comment: Why can't you use code behind?  A converter has code behind.

Comment: it`s ok MR.BalamBalam now please can you tell me how can i do it using Converter.

Comment: Why can't you use code-behind? I often see people mistakenly thinking that using the MVVM design pattern means no code behind should be used at all, and that is wrong. It's perfectly acceptable to put View-Specific code in your code-behind when using the MVVM design pattern.

Comment: No I won't show you how because I don't think a converter is the right tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle this completly in XAML i believe you have two choices:

1. Use `ToggleButton` instead of a `Button` and bind the `IsChecked` property of `ToggleButton` to Grid's `Visiblity` through some kind of BoolToVisibilityConverter.
2. Use `EventTrigger`.

Though i think you'll be just making your life harder. Is there a reason why you would not go with a regular `TabControl` with this?